# how to call html file in action tag using url in django python

Tags: python, html, django

How do i call the html file(register.html) in action tag by using url statement i used liked this..

register.html

In views, i am having the register function, but this is not working, how to use the url in action tag. My project name is loginnew, having the folder template inside register.html file is available.

My register definition in views,

```
def register(request):
    # Like before, get the request's context.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render_to_response('/', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting and the register.html template

Comment: I m geeting the register page in browser  and i filled all the details, if i click the register button ..it show the error..

Comment: Whats the error you are getting. Plus can you share the <form></form> tag you are getting on your template.

Comment: <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/loginnew/templates/register/"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <!-- Display each form. The as_p method wraps each element in a paragraph
                 (<p>) element. This ensures each element appears on a new line,
                 making everything look neater. -->
            {{ user_form.as_p }}
            {{ profile_form.as_p }}

            <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
        </form>

Comment: You haven't shared the error you are facing. Is it related to CSRF verification failed ?

Comment: My error is...Page not found (404)
Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/loginnew/templates/register/

Comment: Do you got my error?...I am the new for stackOverflow..today only i  registered,,..

Comment: It seems like your url structure is not wel formed.
Well you should always provide all details that will help others to understand your question completly. As its seems that you are trying this from some tutorial. But still please provide all the information regarding question like ur url pattern, forms etc.

Comment: As you got 404 error that means your are unable to cummunicate with your view function. It might be due the action url not matching your url pattern in urls.py

Comment: Ok thanks for your clear explanation..its used me to fix that error...Now i can run properly..Thank you..

Comment: I think you should answer your own question below so that it can be helful for others.

Comment: Hi good morng..Now i m getting csrf error..while enter the submit button for login processs..what should i do??

Comment: i would like you to please update your question and provide all the details as i mentioned above.